# How to work with the COUNTER in Nagios or RRD?

Tags: statistics, counter, nagios, rrdtool, rrd

I have the following problem:

I want to do the statistics of data that need to be constantly increasing. For example, the number of visits to the link. After some time be restarted these visit and start again from the beginning. To have a continuous increase, want to do the statistics somewhere. For this purpose, use a site that does this. In his condition can be used to COUNTER, GAUGE, AVERAGE, ... a.. I want to use the COUNTER. The system is built on Nagios.

My question is how to use this COUNTER. I guess it is the same as that of the RRD. But I met some strange things in the creation of such a COUNTER.

I submit the values ' 1 ' then ' 2 ' and the chart to come up 3. When I do it doesn't work. After the restart, for example, and submit again 1 to become 4

Anyone dealt with these things tell me briefly how it works with this COUNTER.

I saw that the COUNTER is used for traffic on routers, etc, but I want to apply for a regular graph, which just increases.

Answer (score 1):

The RRD data type `COUNTER` will convert the input data into a rate, by taking the difference between this sample and the last sample, and dividing by the time interval (note that data normalisation also takes place and this is dependent on the Interval setting of the RRD)

Thus, updating with a constantly increasing count will result in a rate-of-change value to be graphed.

If you want to see your graph actually constantly increasing, IE showing the actual count of packets transferred (for example) rather than the rate of transfer, you would need to use type `GAUGE` which assumes any rate conversion has already been done.

If you want to submit the rate values (EG, 2 in the last minute), but display the overall constantly increasing total (in other words, the inverse of how the `COUNTER` data type works), then you would need to store the values as GAUGE, and use a `CDEF` in your RRDgraph command of the form `CDEF:x=y,PREV,+` to obtain the ongoing total.  Of course you would only have this relative to the start of the graph time window; maybe a separate call would let you determine what base value to use.

As you use Nagios, you may like to investigate Nagios add-ons such as `pnp4nagios` which will handle much of the graphing for you.